# Inverse Relation of Irreflexive Property.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, inverse

We are taking the inverse of relation to check that inverse of R is transitive, reflexive , symmetric and anti-symmetric to as it is on R (not inverse).. My question is that why we are not taking the inverse relation of irreflexive ?